# Getting a Compile error when trying to create matrix with user input. JAVA

Tags: java, user-input

I'm getting a compile error when I try to get matrix Size. I know nothing is wrong with the main method as my instructor told us not to change it. So I'm guessing something is wrong with getMatixSize method. Compiler computation of the program:

> error: method getMatrixSize in class TesterProject cannot be applied
>   to given types;

import java.util*; is already inputted in the program.

```
public class TesterProject
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int n = getMatrixSize();
        int[][] m = makeAndFillMatrix(n);
        printMatrix(m);
    }
    public static int getMatrixSize(int n)
    {
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("give me a int to create the matrix");
        int n = S.nextInt();
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, `getMatrixSize(int n)` _requires_ an `int` argument, but when you invoke it you don't provide an argument.  Beyond that, `getMatrixSize()` does not actually use the value passed in, so you could change the signature to `public static int getMatrixSize()` to make it work.

Comment: Wow k, Thank you and the other users for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call `int n = getMatrixSize();` with no arguments, but your method `public static int getMatrixSize(int n)` accepts an integer as argument. That's the reason you are getting an error.

Remove `int n` from parameter of `getMatrixSize()` and your code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `getMatrixSize` takes an `int` as an argument, and you aren't giving it that.

```
int n = getMatrixSize(5); //pass some int
```

Also, in your `getMatrixSize`, `n` is already declared.

```
public static int getMatrixSize(int n)
{
    Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("give me a int to create the matrix");
    int n = S.nextInt(); //error, n is already declared in the arguments.
    return n;
}
```

or remove the argument and fix it all:

```
public static int getMatrixSize() // removed argument
```